# How to store my type string coming from server to cache?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an **Iphone application** in which i am displaying icon images coming from the server for each type of categories as cell images.i want it to be loaded from my image cache.i want it to be store that image for that type in image cache,and the next time when that type is coming it can be directly loaded from cache.So that if that type image is there it needs to be loaded from local.other wise needs to store and then display.My question is how i can store that image corresponding to that type in image cache,and how i can check it the next time.Can anybody help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

There are several technique to use cache. some are the following i was used .

1-[EGOCache](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache)

2-[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/)

Answer (score 0):

You would try this:  ( for corresponding images you need save image names - in example - nsuser defaults):

```
- (void) makeCache: (NSString *)name
{
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *imagePath = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];  

   // create screen dump of the view of this view controller
   NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
   NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@.jpg", imagePath, fileName];

   NSData *imageBytes = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageIcon.image, .9);  // myImageIcon.image - uiimageview



   BOOL saved = [imageBytes writeToFile: filePath atomically: YES];
   if (!saved)
       {
    NSLog(@"error! can't save image at path: %@", filePath);
   }
```

}

then implement:

```
    - (NSString *) searchFile: (NSString *) fileName
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *imagePath = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", imagePath, fileName];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: filePath])
        {
        return filePath;
    }
    else 
        {
    return nil;
    }
```

}

You also can do this for png images. Good luck!

Comment: i wanted to add a string and image to my cache,ie that string value is the type like if it is a coffeeshop its cofeeshop,or restaurent like that.and there will be corresponding images also.then i need if the type is cofee then add the image from the cache if it is there.else store it and display

Comment: add to nsuser defaults to dictionary: key - type of image (coffeeshop) and value - filePath (from searchFile) This is approximate peace of code, you may override it to your need